# Why next-i18next is always routing to EN in Safari?

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

`next-i18next` works but not on Safari.

I even set regional localizations in our Next.js app, because Safari usually does not pass `hu` but `hu-hu`. I would not create a separate translation json for regional differences. So both `hu` and `hu-hu` should use the Hungarian JSON in the subfolder. But strange though that english is loaded, when opening site in Safari. Why? Am I using something wrong? With `i18next` it all worked. Even the `defaultLocale` is set to `hu`.

```js
const { nextI18NextRewrites } = require("next-i18next/rewrites");

const localeSubpaths = {
  hu: "hu",
  "hu-hu": "hu",
  "hu-HU": "hu",
  en: "en",
};

module.exports = {
  rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    localeSubpaths,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"],
  },
  defaultLocale: "hu",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parameter:

```
load : 'languageOnly'
```